# Getting DATE value from oracle forms using USER EXIT

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-pro-c

I'm trying to user EXEC TOOLS GET to retrieve a date field from ORACLE FORMS into a char variable like this :

```
EXEC TOOLS GET filter.generation_depuis INTO :qstrGenerationDepuis;
```

When I try to display the variable qstrGenerationDepuis I get this value :

```
27-JANV.-2
```

Instead of :

```
27/01/2020
```

Knowing that qstrGenerationDepuis variable is declared as string of 10 characters.

How should I retrieve the field in the user-exit to get the right date format ?

The extension of the user-exit file is .pcs

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about two-step procedure?

First get the value:

```
EXEC TOOLS GET filter.generation_depuis INTO :qstrGenerationDepuis;
```

which sets the item to `27-JANV.-2`

Then convert it to desired format, but **first** you have to know which format you got. This is French, isn't it? Looks like `27th of January of` ... which year? What is `-2`? It can be any year between 2020 and 2029 because variable is 10 characters long:

```
SQL> select to_char(date '2020-01-27', 'dd-MON-yy', 'nls_date_language = french') datum from dual;

DATUM
-----------
27-JANV.-20
         ^ tenth character is "2"; "0" is lost
12345678901
```

If we *presume* that it is the *current year*, then you might try something like this:

- convert a string `27-JANV.-2` into a date by adding current year's last digit (that's what `substr` does)
- apply `to_char` to a new date value, `27-JANV.-20`, with desired format mask

  ```
  SQL> select to_char(to_date('27-JANV.-2' || substr(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy'), -1),
    2                         'dd-mon-rr',
    3                         'nls_date_language = french'),
    4                 'dd/mm/yyyy') result
    5  from dual;

  RESULT
  ----------
  27/01/2020
  ```

Not that it is impossible (obviously), but - you'd rather

- return desired format mask from `filter.generation_depuis`
- or, if that's not possible, enlarge item/variable length to at least 11 characters because you'll lose the last digit

Note that you probably don't have to use `nls_date_language` parameter; I do, as my database runs in Croatian and our format is quite different than yours.